# Ubuntu command line, not recognizing common commands and permission errors as well

Tags: command-line-interface, ubuntu-18.04

I am facing a very weird problem, just cannot put my finger on it.

I am migrating my website from shared hosting to a self-managed VPS on AWS LightSail. I tarballed the entire `public_html` directory on the (shared hosting) source site and scp'd it to my destination VPS. The destination VPS is running Ubuntu 18.04.

At the VPS end, I untarred the archive (`tar xvf website.tar.gz`) within the website root directory and it got untarred there, predictably within the `public_html` sub-directory within the `<website_root>` directory.

But then when I try to move the contents of the `<website_root>/public_html` directory to the `<website_root>/` directory, it gives me a `permission denied` error. But when I try to sudo and enter it like so:

`$ sudo cd public_html/`

it says:

> cd: command not found.

I even tried moving the contents of the public_html directory into the root folder like so:

`$ sudo mv public_html/* .`

and the error it gives me is:

> mv: cannot stat 'public_html/*': No such file or directory.

At my wits end, I just cannot figure out where I'm going wrong.

Comment: `cd` is a shell-builtin, where sudo wants a path to a programme to execute. You could try using `sudo -i` to become root, and allow you to `cd`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `sudo cd` to enter a directory where you don't have access to. `cd` is a shell builtin, not a binary that is executed.

If you don't have access to the directory, you can't list the files there either, that's why you get `No such file or directory.` with `mv public_html/*`.

Become root and move the files afterwards.

```bash
sudo -i
cd public_html
mv * /to/target/dir/
logout
```

Alternatively you could change the permissions of that directory so you can read it (`chmod a+r public_html`, don't forget to revert this when you don't need it anymore) or use the output of `sudo ls`:

```bash
sudo ls public_html |xargs -I "{}" sudo mv {} /to/target/dir/
```

If you have a large number of files, or files with spaces it becomes more complicated.